# How is object static if it's getting dropped?

Tags: rust

I'm very confused on what `'static` means in trait bounds.

I have the following code:

```
pub trait MyTrait : 'static{}
struct HoldsVec<>{
    value: Vec<i32>,
}
impl MyTrait for HoldsVec{}
impl Drop for HoldsVec{
    fn drop(&mut self){
        println!("Dropping HoldsVec with items: {:?}", self.value);
    }
}


pub fn put_in_box<T>(value : T) -> Box<dyn MyTrait> where T : MyTrait{
    Box::new(value)
}

#[test]
pub fn check_lifetimes(){
    let holds_vec = HoldsVec{value: vec![1, 2, 3]};
    drop(holds_vec);
    println!("Code still running");
}


#[test]
pub fn check_lifetimes2(){
    let holds_vec = HoldsVec{value: vec![4, 5, 6]};
    let boxed = put_in_box(holds_vec);
    drop(boxed);
    println!("Code still running");
}

//Only this one won't compile:
#[test]
pub fn check_lifetimes3(){
    let holds_vec = HoldsVec{value: vec![4, 5, 6]};
    let holds_vec_ref : &HoldsVec = &holds_vec;
    let refeference: &'static  HoldsVec = &holds_vec;
}
```

The function `put_in_box` will not compile if I remove the `: 'static` supertrait from `MyTrait`. However, I can implement it for values that are clearly not `static` (If the drop code is run before program termination, it's not static, right?)

Additionally, the last test won't compile - it complains that `holds_vec` will not live long enough, i.e., it's not static, despite implementing a trait that extends static.

Comment: https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/common-rust-lifetime-misconceptions.md#2-if-t-static-then-t-must-be-valid-for-the-entire-program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I can implement it for values that are clearly not `static` (If the drop code is run before program termination, it's not static, right?)

`trait MyTrait: 'static` followed by `where T: MyTrait` implies `T: 'static`. But notice this is a bound on the *type*, not on the *values of that type* — that is, it constrains what types can be `T`, not only what values can be passed in once you have chosen the type.

Any time you write a bound on a type (whether it is a lifetime bound `T: 'static` or a trait bound `T: MyTrait`) you're specifying some property that has to be true of **all** values of the type, not just a property that could be true about some values of that type and false about others.

So, a lifetime bound cannot be about whether values live for `'static`, because you are always free to take any value of any type and drop it. Instead, when you have a lifetime bound `T: 'static`, that means:

- Values of type `T` are guaranteed *not* to contain any references whose lifetimes *don't* equal or outlive `'static`. (This is usually satisfied by not containing any references at all, as your `HoldsVec` doesn't.)
- As a consequence of that property, any value of type `T` *can be made to* live as long as the `'static` lifetime, *by its owner*, because there is nothing that would stop its owner from doing so. But its owner does not have to actually do that; its owner can choose to drop it instead (as you determined empirically).
- This bound is necessary, but **not sufficient** for `&'static T` references to exist. You can create a `&'static T` reference only if you *also* arrange for the *particular value* to live indefinitely, such as by putting it in a `const`, `static`, or `Box::leak()`.

Comment: "But notice this is a bound on the type, not on the values of that type" - I'm struggling to reconcile this with what I've seen elsewhere, which is that Types cannot have lifetimes (they've ceased to exist before runtime begins.) So this is not a question of how long the type itself, lasts, right?

Comment: @EdwardPeters I don't mean that the lifetime is about time during compilation. I mean that the lifetime bound describes a property that will be true about **all** values of the type, not a property that may be true about some individual values of that type and false about others. I've revised my answer to try to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

`put_in_box()` returns `Box<dyn MyTrait>`. The only thing that we've told the compiler about type `T` is that it implements `MyTrait`. `T` might be `Sized` or not, or may even be a reference.
If you change `put_in_box()` to return `Box<T>` instead of `Box<dyn MyTrait>`, then `MyTrait` does not need to be static anymore.

```
pub fn put_in_box<T>(value : T) -> Box<T> 
    where T : MyTrait
{
    Box::new(value)
}
```